# Get different random numbers when using jsp export to excel

Tags: jsp, export-to-excel

After generated 10 random numbers on jsp, then click 'export to excel' button. The generated excel shows 10 different numbers.
[random numbers on jsp page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4231.png)

[random numbers on excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTIpf.png)

Why this happens? And how to fix this problem?

The jsp file < body >'s code shows below:

```
<%
    String exportToExcel = request.getParameter("exportToExcel");
    if (exportToExcel != null
            && exportToExcel.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("YES")) {
        response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename="
                + "excel.xls");

    }

    for(Integer i=0;i<10;i++){
        String randomNum = (RandomStringUtils.random(1, false, true));
%>
        <%=randomNum%>
        <br/>
    <%
    }
    if (exportToExcel == null) {
    %>
        <br/>
        <a href="./test/randomNum.jsp?exportToExcel=YES"><button>Export to Excel</button></a>
    <%
    }
    %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you make a new request each time, and each time a new set of numbers get generated.

Request 1: Generate Numbers
Then you click on the link and another request is made which generated a new set of numbers you see on your excel sheet.

To be able to export the first request numbers, you have to save them in your session and retrieve them:

Consider this example code:

```
<%@page import="java.util.Random"%>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%
            String exportToExcel = request.getParameter("exportToExcel");
            if (exportToExcel != null
                    && exportToExcel.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("YES")) {
                response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
                response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename="
                        + "excel.xls");

                ArrayList<Integer> numbers = (ArrayList<Integer>)session.getAttribute("NUMBERS");
                for(Integer x:numbers){
                    out.print(x);
                    out.print("<br/>");
                }

            } else {
                ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                Random rand = new Random();
                for (Integer i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    String randomNum = String.valueOf(rand.nextInt());
                    numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(randomNum));

        %>
        <%=randomNum%>
        <br/>
        <%
            }
            if (exportToExcel == null) {
        %>
        <br/>
        <a href="randomNum.jsp?exportToExcel=YES"><button>Export to Excel</button></a>
        <%                }
                //store arraylist in session
                session.setAttribute("NUMBERS", numbers);
            }
        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

And will output:

[image]

Hope this helps...

Comment: May I ask If I want to add one more column, how should it change?
Also, how can I save the table header into excel when I made as a table?

Comment: Instead of just outputting a number in a different line `out.print(x);out.print("<br/>");` you should build an html table style element